# Extracting Excel cell format with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C#

Tags: c#, performance, excel

I am trying to fetch the format (e.g. background color, border settings) of each cell in Excel file with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel class. I know that there are many tools could be used well in data reading, such as ExcelDataReader. However, many of them cannot retrieve cell format (https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/48, https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/87). The problem is that Excel interop is slow because this way is basically remote-controlling an instance of the Excel application. The following code is used for fetching the background color of each cell in Excel file. Could I make any other improvements? All suggestions are welcome.

The size of Test.xlsx here is 20 row * 9 column and runTime is 00:00:04.53, 00:00:03.25 and 00:00:03.21 @intel(r) core(tm) i9-9900k cpu.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CsharpMicrosoftOfficeInteropExcelApplicationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FilenameInput = "./Test.xlsx";

            Console.WriteLine("Open file: " + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + FilenameInput + System.Environment.NewLine);
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();              //  for code performance measurement
            stopWatch.Start();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(
                System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + FilenameInput);

            
            for (uint LoopNumberX = 0; LoopNumberX < ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets["Test"].UsedRange.Columns.Count; LoopNumberX++)
            {
                for (uint LoopNumberY = 0; LoopNumberY < ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets["Test"].UsedRange.Rows.Count; LoopNumberY++)
                {
                    System.Drawing.Color SystemDrawingColor = GetBackgroundColor(ExcelWorkbook, "Test", LoopNumberX, LoopNumberY);
                    Console.WriteLine("Location: (" + LoopNumberX.ToString() + ", " + LoopNumberY.ToString() + ")\tColor=" + SystemDrawingColor.ToString());
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();

            // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

            // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static private System.Drawing.Color GetBackgroundColor(
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WorkbookObject,
            string SheetName,
            uint LocationX,
            uint LocationY
            )
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet = WorkbookObject.Worksheets[SheetName];
            return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(
                System.Convert.ToInt32(ExcelWorksheet.Cells[LocationY + 1, LocationX + 1].Interior.Color)
                );
        }
    }
}
```

**Oct 7, 2020 Update**

Based on the above code, the input parameter "LocationX" and "LocationY" of the GetBackgroundColor method are separated, is it a good idea to bundle them together for better readability?

```
        static private System.Drawing.Color GetBackgroundColor(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WorkbookObject,
        string SheetName,
        Tuple<uint, uint> Location              //  Location.Item1 is LocationX, and Location.Item2 is LocationY
            )
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorksheet = WorkbookObject.Worksheets[SheetName];
            return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(
                System.Convert.ToInt32(ExcelWorksheet.Cells[Location.Item2 + 1, Location.Item1 + 1].Interior.Color)
                );
        }
```

Comment: Tip: For the code readability you may add `using System.Drawing;` and change all `System.Drawing.Color` to `Color` then. And the same for other namesapces.